# how to fix specific query to use pagination using python

Tags: python, mysql, pagination

I'm setting up a pagination on chat application which only allow first 10 on a page using flask python and mysql

```
@app.route('/chats', defaults={'page':1}, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/chats/page/<int:page>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def chats(page):
  if 'lid' in session:
    id = session['lid']
    uid = session['uid']
    # Create cursor
    perpage = 10
    startat = page * perpage
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    # Get message
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM message WHERE (msg_by=%s AND msg_to=%s) 
                OR (msg_by=%s AND msg_to=% s) limit %s, %s"
                "ORDER BY id ASC", (uid, id, id, uid)(startat,perpage))
    chats = cur.fetchall()
    # Close Connection
    cur.close()
    return render_template('chats.html', chats=chats,)
  return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

this show me error (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; but I can't find, if anyone there to solve this please help,thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to first use `ORDER BY` then apply `LIMIT` according to SQL standards.

Change your sql query to:

```py
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM message WHERE (msg_by=%s AND msg_to=%s) 
             OR (msg_by=%s AND msg_to=% s) ORDER BY id ASC limit %s, %s", 
            (uid, id, id, uid)(startat,perpage))
```

Comment: @Shek Mark this as the answer then to help others